# How can I get good-quality text when using a RenderTargetBitmap?

Tags: c#, wpf

I need to create a small, simple TIFF image that is just black text on a white background, as part of a support library we use across several of our products. (Think a simple receipt or deposit ticket, that kind of thing). I would prefer not to have to use any third-party libraries, to avoid requiring us to add additional dependencies to all of the existing products that use the library.

I have almost gotten the problem solved using just WPF, based on the code from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10439621/creating-tiff-image-at-runtime-in-wpf). The TIFF is created and rendered properly, but the text quality is horrible. As far as I can determine, the problem is that `RenderTargetBitmap`, at least the way I'm using it, isn't doing any kind of anti-aliasing, isn't using ClearType, or otherwise is just really bad at rendering plain text, e.g.:

[image: Sample Rendered Text]

I've read similar questions, such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5292321/wpf-rendertargetbitmap-downscaling-textrendermode-to-greyscale) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9083982/can-i-get-textformattingmode-display-while-drawing-off-screen-e-g-rendertarget), but they all seem to discuss how to capture text from a visual control or window handle without reducing the quality. I'm doing this entirely off-screen, so I'm not clear if/how I can apply those solutions to my problem.

What I'm currently doing is:

```
var visual = new DrawingVisual();
using (var draw = visual.RenderOpen())
{
    // 'background' is a pre-loaded blank white bitmap
    draw.DrawImage(background, new Rect(0, 0, IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT));

    var font = new Typeface("Segoe UI");
    Func<string, FormattedText> format = s => new FormattedText(
        s,
        CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture, 
        FlowDirection.LeftToRight, 
        font, 
        16, 
        Brushes.Black);

    draw.DrawText(format("Some text"), new Point(HEADER_LEFT, HEADER_TOP);

    // Call draw.DrawText a whole bunch more times.
        .
        .
        .
}

var render = new RenderTargetBitmap(IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_DPI, IMG_DPI, PixelFormats.Default);
render.Render(visual);

var encoder = new TiffBitmapEncoder()
{
    Compression = TiffCompressOption.Ccitt4
};
encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(render));

var stream = new MemoryStream();
encoder.Save(stream);
```

Is there something else I can put in there to get the text quality better than what it is?

Comment: So, bitonal is a requirement. Is the choice of font a requirement as well? For small, bitonal images, I wonder if bitmap fonts (etc) aren't the best choice if you can constrain your use case enough - what sizes do you need?

Comment: no, the font was arbitrary, I can pick anything that has a roughly 10-14 point size. I'll try some others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `Ccitt4`, it's for black-and-white images only. Try `Default` instead.

UPDATE:

It's a TT font and you're trying to render it at a small size, no matter what you do it's going to look pretty crap. Still, if you insist then don't use a visual. Screen elements use hardware acceleration, when you use them with a render target as you are here it has to fall back to a software approach which isn't always pixel-for-pixel the same. And either way you always get at least some aliasing. If you really do want proper bitonal then you'll have to use a Graphics object which will use GDI:

```
var bitmap = new Bitmap(512, 256);
var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap);
graphics.Clear(System.Drawing.Color.White);
var font = new Font("Segoe UI", 16);
graphics.TextRenderingHint = System.Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.SingleBitPerPixelGridFit;
graphics.DrawString("Hello World", font, System.Drawing.Brushes.Black, 0, 0);


ImageCodecInfo myImageCodecInfo = GetEncoderInfo("image/tiff");
var myEncoderParameters = new EncoderParameters(1);
myEncoderParameters.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Compression, (long)EncoderValue.CompressionCCITT4);
bitmap.Save(@"myimage.tif", myImageCodecInfo, myEncoderParameters);
graphics.Dispose();


    private static ImageCodecInfo GetEncoderInfo(String mimeType)
    {
        int j;
        ImageCodecInfo[] encoders;
        encoders = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders();
        for (j = 0; j < encoders.Length; ++j)
        {
            if (encoders[j].MimeType == mimeType)
                return encoders[j];
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Result (which SO is blurring a bit itself):

[image]

Comment: CCITT4 is a requirement in this case, and I've seen plenty of good-quality bitonal text images.

Comment: For some reason I have an aversion to using GDI+ for TIFFs but in this case the work is simple enough. Thanks for the nudge :)